# Prove that if two continuous functions have equal integrals over interval then the functions are equal at a point c in interval.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Here is the statement I am struggling to prove.

Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous functions on [a,b], and that $\int^b_a f(x)=\int^b _a g(x)$. Prove there exists a point $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$.

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me construct a simple yet concise proof of this statement using basic real analysis techniques. I was thinking that you would use some form of the idea that $\inf (f(x)-g(x))=0$ except at some point c? Then you could construct an interval around this point to show this is a true statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can apply the ["Mean Value Theorems for Definite Integrals"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_Value_Theorems_for_Definite_Integrals) to $f-g$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$. Then $h$ is continuous, and the condition $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b g(x) dx$ is equivalent to
$$\int_a^b h(x) dx = 0$$
If $h(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b h(x) dx > 0$ since $h$ is continuous. Similarly, if $h(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b h(x) dx < 0$. Since neither of these is true, the only other possibility is that $h(x) < 0$ and $h(y) > 0$ for some $x,y \in [a,b]$. Now apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty close to what I was thinking, however I managed to  overcomplicated it with the idea of constructing an interval around c.

Comment: There is a bit of work to do to show that if $h(x) > 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b h(x) dx > 0$. You can show this, for example, by choosing some $c\in [a,b]$ and letting $\epsilon = h(c)/2$. Then there is an interval $I = (c-\delta/2, c+\delta/2)$ in which $h(x) > \epsilon$, so the integral over $I$ is at least $\epsilon \delta > 0$. Since $h(x) > 0$ everywhere in $[a,b]$, this means that the integral over $[a,b]$ must be  positive. I omitted this from the answer because it's just a technical detail which clutters the main argument without adding any insight.

Comment: It is a bit easier for continuous functions: $h$ attains a *minimum* $m$ on the interval, and $m > 0$ implies that the integral is $\ge (b-a)m > 0$.

Comment: @martin Nice, that's much simpler.